# Getting multiple rows using ParamConverter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi Im trying to use ParamConverter to get multiple rows from DB but profiler show query with `limi 1`. Is it possible to get it like that

```
/**
* @Route("/localization/{code}", name="pkt-index")
* @ParamConverter("localizations", class="PriceBundle:Localization")
*/
```

after entering `localization/0003` I should get more than 100 rows.

**EDIT:**
I have used `repository_method` option 
and

```
/*
* @Route("/localization/{id}", name="pkt-index")
* @ParamConverter("localizations", class="PriceBundle:Localization", options={
* "repository_method": "getByLocalizationCode"
* })
*/
```

but funny thing is that when I change `{id}` in route it does not work it throws and exception
`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`
even if variable exists in entity class, if variable dont exist it throws
`Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information.`

**EXPLANATION**

> when I change `{id}` in route it does not work it throws and exception
>   `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

Here I think symfony treads `id` like primary key and as parameter to repository method it pass `string` when I changed this `id` to something else it pass `array`

Example

```
/**
* @Route("/localization/{id}", name="pkt-index")
*/
```

pass `string` to method

```
/**
* @Route("/localization/{code}/{name}", name="pkt-index")
*/
```

pass `array` to method

```
array(
    'code' => 003
    'name' => localization_name
)
```

and last

```
/**
* @Route("/localization/{id}/{name}", name="pkt-index")
*/
```

will pass `string` id omit the name

Hope this sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

forgottenbas's answer isn't completely right. `@ParamConverter` will first try to find one entity by id ...

... then try to [match the route variables against db columns](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php#L110) to find an entity ... 
but essentially it will only convert one entity at a time.

If you would still like to use a paramconverter you would need to write a custom one.

or just use a one-liner inside your controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/localization/{code}", name="pkt-index")
 */
public function yourAction($code)
{
     $localizations = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("YourBundle:Localization")->findBy(array("code" => $code));
     // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`ParamConverter` currently can only extract id from request and find one entity from db. Look at 
[DoctrineParamConverter](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php) code. But you can specify your [own param converter](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/02/19/extending_symfony2__paramconverter.html) with some extra logic.

Comment: does that mean ParamConverter would never work inside of a Entity setter function?